# MFC Property Grid Formatted Floats

Tags: c++, mfc

So I'm working on an editor-style application using C++ / MFC in Visual Studio 2008.

The default wizard project for a visual studio style application is full of useful goodness, but doesn't address everything, and even a few MFC books I found don't mention this particular question.

How do you go about getting a property viewer using `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` that displays a floating point value to limit the number of decimal places it shows?  Right now, you seem to get 6 decimal places on a float value (constructed using a floating point `_variant_t`).  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` has a virtual function called `FormatProperty()`. This function returns a `CString` object that contains the string representation of the property's value. It is called by the framework when the property value needs to be displayed.

Since the function is virtual, you can derive your own property class from `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` and override that function so that the base class's implementation will be invoked in the general case, while your own formatting logic will be applied when the 
corresponding variant has type `VT_R4` (`float`) or `VT_R8` (`double`).

Something like this:

```
class CMyProperty : CMFCPropertyGridProperty
{
    ...
    virtual CString FormatProperty()
    {
        CString str;
        if (GetValue().vt == VT_R8)
        {
            str.Format(...); // Or whatever you want
        }
        else
        {
            str = CMFCPropertyGridProperty::FormatProperty();
        }

        return str;
    }
};
```

Then, you could pass instances of your own property class `CMyProperty` to `CMFCPropertyGrid`'s function `AddProperty()`.

Comment: Andy - thanks for the answer, I have gotten it mostly working.  Do you happen to know how to get it to call 'FormatProperty' on construction?  It appears that it does not format the property until after a value is set.  The solution may be as simple as creating and then calling 'SetValue', but I was hoping for something better.  Thanks!

Comment: @James: `FormatProperty()` is a virtual function, so you shouldn't try to call it on construction (meaning: in your class's constructor). But maybe I misunderstood what you were really asking for? Why do you want it to be called on construction? I assumed the framework would call it any time its value needs to be displayed, isn't it so?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, but it looks like if you initialize a `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` via the constructor and do not call `SetValue`, then the function is never called and you get the default format.  Likely because of what you said - it can't call a virtual function in the constructor.

Comment: @James: I'm not sure I understand: if you never set a value, then what do you expect to be displayed? I guess the type of the encapsulated variant is just not `VT_R8` if no value is set, so your formatting code which is in the corresponding branch of the `if` statement does not get executed. Have you tried debugging it to see what's going on?